# Get screen position of the center of a mesh

Tags: c++, qt, 3d, rotation, qml

My goal is to create an intuitive 3D manipulator to handle rotations of meshes displayed in my 3D editor, made with Qt / QML.

To do that, when the user clicks on an entity, 3 tori are spawned around the mesh, representing the euler angles the user can act on. If the user then clicks on one torus, I want him to be able to rotate the mesh by dragging the mouse. The natural way users seem to do that is by dragging the mouse around the torus in the direction they want the mesh to rotate.

I therefore need a way to know how the user is rotating his mouse. I thought of a way: when the user clicks on the torus, I retrieve the position of the center of the torus. Then, I translate this world position to its screen position. Then, I monitor the angle between the cursor of the mouse and the center of the torus. The evolution of this angle *should* tell me everything I need: if the angle increases clockwise, the mesh should rotate clockwise and vice versa. This solution should yield a result good enough for my application, since it won't depend on the angle of the camera, or only very minimally.

However, I can't find a way to translate a world position to its screen position with Qt. I found the function `QVector3D::project(const QMatrix4x4 &modelView, const QMatrix4x4 &projection, const QRect &viewport)`, but its documentation is very scarce and I couldn't find anyone using it... I might have found what to feed in for the `projection` argument (the `projectionMatrix` property from QCamera, here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt3d-render-camera.html), but that's it. What is the `modelView` ? And `viewport` ? Is it simply `QRect(0, 0, 1920, 1080)` ?

If anyone have any kind of lead, it would be amazing, I can't find anything anywhere and I'm kind of losing hope now. Or maybe another, simpler, solution to my problem ? Please note that the user can also freely move the camera around the mesh, which adds in complexity.

Thanks a lot for your time, and have a nice day !

Comment: Why not simply use the horizontal or vertical distance from the first "mouse down point" and multiply by that some fraction of a full rotation for the corresponding angle?

Comment: @Botje Because it depends on where the user clicks. If he clicks on the bottom of the torus, he first needs to go left then up to rotate clockwise, whereas if he clicks on the top of the torus, the needs to go right and down. Basically, I would need to create a special case for every point on the torus, and for every camera angle. Maybe I misunderstand something though, it's the first time I work on a project like that. Your kind of solution works well for translations and scaling though, but for rotations I can't think of a way to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to translate from world position to screen position using the mentioned function. You are correct about the `projection` argument. As for the `modelView` argument, you should use `viewMatrix` property from QCamera, which is missing from the official documentation, but it works for me. The `viewport` parameter represents the dimensions of the part of the screen, you are projecting on. You could use `QRect(0, 0, 1920, 1080)` if you use full screen Full HD projection, otherwise use something like `QRect(QPoint(0, 0), view->size())`, where `view` is the wigdet or window with your 3D image. Be careful, that the resulting screen position will have `y = 0` being down and positive values being above, which the opposite to usual screen coordinates.